# Need OSX virtualenv to download .so in addition to .dylibs

Tags: python, macos, pip, virtualenv, aws-lambda

I'm creating a deployment package for AWS Lambda. Lambda requires zipping of all the contents contained inside of `'$VIRTUALENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages'` folder after installing the packages in a `virtualenv`.

When I do this process on a linux machine, it works smoothly.
But when I repeat this process from a Mac (Mac Sierra), I run into a small issue.
Mac downloads `.dylibs` instead of `.so` when I do a `pip install Pillow`. 
And hence deployment on Lambda fails.

I verified, that if I put the `.so` from a linux machine for Pillow package, it works on AWS.

Is there any way to download `.so` in addition to `.dylibs` when working with virtualenv on a Mac? This will allow me to seamlessly deploy packages from Mac to AWS Lambda.

My project is slightly big in size. And Pillow is not the only package I might need which runs into such problems.

Answer (score 1):

`virtualenv` downloads packages that work with the Python interpreter used to run it. As far as I can see there is no option for cross-compiling packages to other architectures.

You cannot run the Linux interpreter natively on OSX, so you will need to use a Linux machine (either a real one, a container or a virtual machine) to construct the correct `virtualenv`.

Probably the most seamless solution is containers (for example [Docker for Mac](https://www.docker.com/docker-mac)).
You could then mount your working directory in a suitable container and create a parallel `virtualenv` for the Linux container.